# Getting id of images in gridview and storing in array in sequence

Tags: android, gridview

I don't know how to get the id of each images from Image Adapter class and store it in array in continuous sequence.
What I have to do is to swap images and after swappin that images, I want to save the ids of all images and store them in array.

ImageAdapter.Java

```
package com.example.dragdropimagepart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ImageView iView;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Item Is :-" + mThumbIds[position].toString());
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Geting Id of Item " + mThumbIds[position]);
        if (iView != null) {
            //iView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            position = iView.getId();
            int[] array ={position};
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call"+ array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            iView = new ImageView(mContext);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            iView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            iView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        iView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return iView;
    }

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.sms1,
            R.drawable.call, R.drawable.android1, R.drawable.android,
            R.drawable.collection };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set onClickListener() your image id will save and image will display for further details provide more details because on click your image indexes will be saved automatically in an array...

Comment: if you can provide some code sniplet or sample, that may help.

Comment: Farhan, check and read your answer, it's required to be updated with English with correct grammar!